# Python Pandas partial slicing and sorting on dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice, data-manipulation

I have an input file of the wavelengths and absorbance from a spectrometer. In this file the data is recorded and just added as the last two columns of the dataframe. The columns are needed to specify the wavelength at which a specific absorbance (=data) was measured.

| Wavelength1 | Data1 | Wavelength2 | Data2 | Wavelength3 | Data3 | and so on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 800 | 0.1 | 798 | 0.02 | 798.5 | 0.6 | and so on |
| 799 | 0.15 | 797 | 0.03 | 798.0 | 0.2 | and so on |
| 798 | 0.133 | 796 | 0.2 | 797.5 | 0.4 | and so on |
| 797 | 0.14 | 795 | 0.052 | 797.0 | 0.34 | and so on |
| and so on | and so on | and so on | and so on | and so on | and so on | and so on |

I would like to have a dataframe that makes my analysis a bit easier. Something like that:

| Wavelength1 | Data1 | Wavelength2 | Data2 | Wavelength3 | Data3 | and so on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 800 | 0.1 | NaN | NaN | 798.5 | 0.6 | and so on |
| 799 | 0.15 | NaN | NaN | 798.0 | 0.2 | and so on |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 798.5 | 0.6 | and so on |
| 798 | 0.133 | 798 | 0.02 | 798.0 | 0.2 | and so on |
| NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN | 797.5 | 0.4 | and so on |
| 797 | 0.14 | 797 | 0.03 | 797.0 | 0.34 | and so on |
| and so on | and so on | and so on | and so on | and so on | and so on | and so on |

With my quite basic python skill set, I know, that I could probably store each wavelength-data pair as a list of tuples and make some complicated sorting magic happening. But every since trying to learn more about the pandas module, I was wondering if I can tackle this problem with more ease. However, while I have found [pandas shift function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), I have not found a way of making it conditional nor shifting and sorting each column individually.

Comment: Can I ask why you have multiple Wavelength columns? Does the DataFrame need to have more than two columns (Wavelength, Data)?

Comment: There are two entries for 796 in "Wavelength2". Which would you keep?

Comment: looks like classic use case for https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html

Comment: @philosofool: You may want to change the number of points between to wavelengths in order to better estimate a certain peak, but in general one wavelength column and multiple data columns should be good.

Comment: @not_speshal: This was a mistake. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

- this is classic [wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)
- your sample data has two readings for wavelength 796 in second set of data.  This effectively means duplicates, dealt with this by putting a **subreading** in place
- finally transform back to long, where values line up on **Wavelength** with provision for duplicates
- clearly steps to convert back to wide and flattening columns are optional based on how you want to run your analysis

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Wavelength1': [800, 799, 798, 797],
 'Data1': [0.1, 0.15, 0.133, 0.14],
 'Wavelength2': [798, 797, 796, 796],
 'Data2': [0.02, 0.03, 0.2, 0.052],
 'Wavelength3': [798.5, 798.0, 797.5, 797.0],
 'Data3': [0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.34]})

# wide to long
df2 = (
    pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ["Wavelength", "Data"], i="index", j="reading")
    .droplevel(0)
    .reset_index()
    .set_index(["Wavelength", "reading"])
)
```

#### long data

```
                     Data
Wavelength reading       
800.0      1        0.100
799.0      1        0.150
798.0      1        0.133
797.0      1        0.140
798.0      2        0.020
797.0      2        0.030
796.0      2        0.200
           2        0.052
798.5      3        0.600
798.0      3        0.200
797.5      3        0.400
797.0      3        0.340
```

#### back to wide with wavelength lined up

```
# long back to wide, delating with duplicate "Wavelength"
df2 = df2.set_index(
    pd.Series(df2.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount().values, name="subreading"),
    append=True,
).unstack("reading")
# flatten the columns..
df2.columns = ["".join(map(str, c)) for c in df2.columns]
```

#### final output

```
                       Data1  Data2  Data3
Wavelength subreading                     
796.0      0             NaN  0.200    NaN
           1             NaN  0.052    NaN
797.0      0           0.140  0.030   0.34
797.5      0             NaN    NaN   0.40
798.0      0           0.133  0.020   0.20
798.5      0             NaN    NaN   0.60
799.0      0           0.150    NaN    NaN
800.0      0           0.100    NaN    NaN
```